# Merging a remote branch with a local repo

Tags: git, github

I have scoured the answer lists for this issue and I can't seem to figure out how git works in this regard.

This is a simple issue I am sure, so I apologize in advance for the newbie content!

I have a remote repository that I have cloned:

git clone git://github.com/package1/package1.git

I have another remote git repository at https://github.com/package2/package2.git that contains some additional patches and programs that have been added to the package1 repo.

What is the best method to pull the contents of package2, and then merge everything with package1?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

If package1 and package2 is originally the same repository, it's something like

```
git remote add -f p2 https://github.com/package2/package2.git
git merge p2/thebranch
```

if not, you just get the diff you want from package2 repository and apply it to package1.

Comment: No, same error I keep getting with the SSL certificate for some reason:  error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) while accessing https://github.com/package2/package2.git/info/refs

Comment: why are some github packages published with https, and others with the git:// protocol handler?

Comment: They are all published with both, you can pick. And I'd suggest that you use `git://` as it's faster. I'm not sure about SSL cert error…